# repaint causes mouseListener to register clicks that didn't happen

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouseevent

I'm doing a program in which the use of JButton is prohibited.  I was asked to use a mouse event listener on an awt rectangle.  The result of clicking the button should be:

- adds 10 to a variable in another class
- repaints a rectangle representing a fuel meter

The problem is that when I place the repaint method at the end of the mouseClicked listener, after the first click, the listener registers multiple clicks instead of one.  Here is a program that implements the same type of button replacement I used (found here on StackExchange):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui2 extends JFrame {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    MyDrawPanel drawpanel = new MyDrawPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gui2 gui = new Gui2();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {

        frame.getContentPane().add(drawpanel);
        // frame.addMouseListener(this);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}

class MyDrawPanel extends JComponent implements MouseListener {
    private boolean mouseClicked = false;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        Color startrandomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

        red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        Color endrandomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70, 70, startrandomColor,
                150, 150, endrandomColor);

        g2d.setPaint(gradient);
        g2d.fillOval(70, 70, 100, 100);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if ((e.getButton() == 1)
                && (e.getX() >= 70 && e.getX() <= 170 && e.getY() >= 70 && e
                .getY() <= 170)) {
            mouseClicked = true;
            this.repaint();
            if(mouseClicked == true){
                System.out.println("click");
            }
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getX()+ "\n" + e.getY());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

When the ellipse in the frame is clicked one time, one "click" is printed on the console.  When it's clicked a second time for some reason it prints 2 "click".  For a third click, it prints 3 and so on.  Why does the repaint method do this and how can I use it on the awt ellipse without it registering multiple clicks?

Comment: Please see edit to answer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: because it was in the project specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add the MouseListener inside of the paintComponent method as that will continue to add **multiple** MouseListeners to your component, and so with each subsequent mouse click, randomization and repainting will be called multiple times, not what you want. Add it once in the class's constructor and your problem is solved. Remember that the paintComponent method should be for painting and painting only, and not for changing components, for adding listeners, for reading in images or for anything else. In fact, I'd set my random colors in the MouseListener, not in paintComponent, else the colors would change when you resized the GUI. Why the boolean variable by the way?  Also, don't forget to add the super.paintComponent call to your paintComponent override. I'd also use mousePressed, not mouseClicked, since mouseClicked can be unreliable. For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui2 {
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   MyDrawPanel drawpanel = new MyDrawPanel();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            Gui2 gui = new Gui2();
            gui.go();
         }
      });
   }

   public void go() {
      frame.getContentPane().add(drawpanel);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}

class MyDrawPanel extends JComponent {
   private static final int PREF_W = 240;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final double RGB_MAX = 255;
   private static final double ELLIPSE_X = 70;
   private static final double ELLIPSE_WIDTH = PREF_W - 2 * ELLIPSE_X;
   private int red;
   private int green;
   private int blue;
   private Color startrandomColor;
   private Color endrandomColor;
   private Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(ELLIPSE_X, ELLIPSE_X,
         ELLIPSE_WIDTH, ELLIPSE_WIDTH);

   public MyDrawPanel() {
      addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
      setRandomGradient();
   }

   private void setRandomGradient() {
      red = (int) (Math.random() * RGB_MAX);
      green = (int) (Math.random() * RGB_MAX);
      blue = (int) (Math.random() * RGB_MAX);
      startrandomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
      red = (int) (Math.random() * RGB_MAX);
      green = (int) (Math.random() * RGB_MAX);
      blue = (int) (Math.random() * RGB_MAX);
      endrandomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70, 70, startrandomColor, 150,
            150, endrandomColor);

      g2d.setPaint(gradient);
      g2d.fill(ellipse);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         if (ellipse.contains(e.getPoint())) {
            setRandomGradient();
            repaint();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Also note that if you use an Ellipse2D, your if block in the MouseListener gets greatly simplified, and this greatly reduces your risk of pernicious hard to find bugs:

```
  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
     if (ellipse.contains(e.getPoint())) {
        setRandomGradient();
        repaint();
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I had tried to separate the listener from the paintComponent, but it never occurred to me to use a class inheriting the MouseAdapter class.